# How to merge two dataframe with no common column

Tags: r

I would like to merge 2 dataframe without common column. Actually this 2 dataframe has same named column but variable in this column has little different name. So I cannot merging them.

Code example:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(gene = c("a1.1", "a2.2"), df_1_value = c("12", "13"))
df_2 <- data.frame(gene = c("a1", "a2"), df_2_value = c("153", "461"))
```

I want to get :

```
    gene                                                   df_1_value       df_2_value
  a1.1 or a1 (it doesnt matter, both of two is same)              12              153
  a2.2 or a2                                                      13              461
```

I try :

```
df22 <- df_2 %
   select(df_2_value)

merge(df_1, df_22)
```

Output :

```
gene                   df_1_value                       df_2_value 
a1.1                      12                                153
a2.2                      13                                153
a1.1                      12                                461
a2.2                      13                                461
```

Comment: You should check out this repo: https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin. It is perfectly tailored for what you're trying to do. Your other option would be to simply modify the column in your second table and standardize the values so that `a1.1` becomes `a1`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the method for translating between the two `gene` formats is clear, you can try this technique to turn this problem into a "by-column" method (vice "fuzzy" method):

```
df_1$genemod <- gsub("\\..*", "", df_1$gene)
merge(df_1, df_2, by.x="genemod", by.y="gene")
#   genemod gene df_1_value df_2_value
# 1      a1 a1.1         12        153
# 2      a2 a2.2         13        461
```

(where you can easily remove or rename either of the `gene` and `genemod` columns)

Answer (score -1):

### 1. If the rows are exactly matched:

```
cbind(df_1, "df_2_value" = df_2[, 2])
  gene df_1_value df_2_value
1 a1.1         12        153
2 a2.2         13        461
```

### 2. If you have spotty data

Best used if `df_2_value` does not exist for all rows or vice-versa.

```
df_1$gene <- substr(df_1$gene, 1, 2)    # Clean up "gene" column
library(dplyr)
full_join(df_1, df_2, "gene")  

  gene df_1_value df_2_value
1   a1         12           
2   a2         13        461
```

Data

```
df_1 <- data.frame(gene = c("a1.1", "a2.2"), df_1_value = c("12", "13"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df_2 <- data.frame(gene = c("a1", "a2"), df_2_value = c("", "461"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: This answer does not match the desired output OP requested.